# why I am getting Application error and Generic page error on JMeter, when running with multiple threads, and when checking same on browser it is fine

Tags: asp.net, .net, jmeter, performance-testing, application-error

It is a .Net application, here Below are the mentioned errors that I am getting when running with multiple thread counts like 50 users, and when trying for the same failed user on to the browser, as well as singly on Jmeter it is working fine there.

The errors are below mentioned :

1. 1|#||4|101|pageRedirect||%2ferrors%2fgenericerrorpage.aspx%3faspxerrorpath%3d%2fpolicyholder%2fduplicatethirdpartycontact.aspx|
2. Application Error :
   We are sorry, but an unhandled error occurred on the server.
   The Server Administrator has been notified and the error logged.
   Please continue on by either clicking the back button and retrying your request or by returning to the home page

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `duplicatethirdpartycontact` bit most probably your application doesn't allow concurrent logins or actions by the same user, you need to think about [parameterizing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) your test

I.e. each JMeter thread (virtual user) should use its own credentials, normally people use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for supplying the test data, however other approaches also exist.

Also make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan.

Comment: for 50 users, what other approach do I need to take, can u help me or suggest me
HTTP Cookie Manager is already added.
And I am using CSV Data Set Config Element for users.

Answer (score 0):

1. by keeping Csv data set config in once only controller(Where Parameter can be used for the next iteration)
2. Use Baolu CSV data set Plugin, there you can get allocated data to a thread as below configurations
   -->set Allocate data to the thread to "true"
   -->Automatically allocate block size to"False"
   --> set block size for each thread to ""as u need"(u can allocate n number of values)